# iPhone CSS Background Resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background

I'm currently working on a WordPress theme and I've got it up & running here: http://tinyurl.com/kawesnh

I'm trying to make the image shown in the background cross-compatible with the iPhone's safari browser, but have failed to do so :)

I'd like to have the background scroll with the page's content, but haven't found how to do this, while also having the background resize for the iPhone browser.

Here's my CSS, which produces an initially good-looking layout on the iPhone, but resizes the content after a link is clicked, also it's producing a bad result on desktop browsing:

**CSS**

```
body { 

background: url(http://www.myurl.co/tq/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/TQ-Oceanside_BGtaller.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-position: center top;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes trying to identify what your problem is exactly and I can't seem to find it.  I opened up the link provided in Chrome and then opened it up in Safari with user agent (Safari - for Windows, and iPhone Safari iOS 4.3.3) the page renders exactly the same across all browsers? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you for checking that out! The good news is that I got it to render properly in iPhone on initial load, but after that it goes crazy, also - in a desktop browser, the background is fixed, which is incorrect but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS3 media queries. Media queries are used by most themes on wordpress because they make your website responsive and makes your background resize to the browser's size. Here's a tutorial:

 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm not familiar with implementing responsive CSS files, in which file should I reference the responsive CSS stylesheet?

Comment: You can put media queries in an external file or in your html document using the <style> tag.